# Changes in QoS 1 and 2 in MQTT 5

Tags: mqtt

According to HiveMQ site here: https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt5-essentials-part2-foundational-changes-in-the-protocol/ a big difference between QoS1 and 2 in version 5 is that "for healthy connection there is no retry" for messages which don't come to destination. I am not sure about the following point:

- I had a look at the standard, I didn't find any mention about it, can someone confirm this is true?
- Does it mean that if the connection breaks while messages are in-flight or messages are not acknowledged because the receiver is not reachable are the only case where there will be a re transmission?
- What about a network congestion but PINGREQ/PINGRES still work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [V5 spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/mqtt-v5.0.html#_Toc385349369) states:

> When a Client reconnects with Clean Start set to 0 and a session is present, both the Client and Server MUST resend any unacknowledged PUBLISH packets (where QoS > 0) and PUBREL packets using their original Packet Identifiers. This is the only circumstance where a Client or Server is REQUIRED to resend messages. Clients and Servers **MUST NOT** resend messages at any other time [MQTT-4.4.0-1].

The "MUST NOT" is a change from the V3 spec (which permitted resending but did not require it). I believe that this answers your second question (the spec is pretty clear that messages must not be resent other than after a reconnection).

> What about a network congestion but PINGREQ/PINGRES still work?

When a `PINGREQ` is received a `PINGRESP` will be sent; if network congestion prevents delivery within the allowed time  window then the connection will be dropped; otherwise it will stay up. TCP provides a guarantee of in order packet delivery so messages should get through eventually (I realise that this does not always work 100%).

I cannot say why this change was made in the v5 spec but the article [you are reading](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt5-essentials-part2-foundational-changes-in-the-protocol/#no-retry-for-qos-1-and-2-messages) states:

> In practice, this is a **very bad idea**, since overloaded MQTT clients may get overloaded even more.

Mosquitto dropped support for retries in [version 1.5](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/ChangeLog.txt) giving the following reasons:

> Outgoing messages with QoS>1 are no longer retried after a timeout period.
> Messages will be retried when a client reconnects.  This change in behaviour
> can be justified by considering when the timeout may have occurred.
>
> - If a connection is unreliable and has dropped, but without one end
>   noticing, the messages will be retried on reconnection. Sending
>   additional PUBLISH or PUBREL would not have changed anything.
> - If a client is overloaded/unable to respond/has a slow connection then
>   sending additional PUBLISH or PUBREL would not help the client catch
>   up. Once the backlog has cleared the client will respond. If it is not
>   able to catch up, sending additional duplicates would not help either.

Comment: this totally answer my questions, thaks!

Comment: thinking about it...it seems that there is now no much difference between QoS 1 and 2 as any re transmission must imply a re connection or am I wrong? Unless multipath can cause delays and is still possible to receive duplicate messages after disconnections, in this case it would make still sense....

Comment: Any time a message is resent there is a potential for a duplicate; QOS 2 avoids this using a four-part handshake. Not resending messages on a timer does reduce, but not eliminate, the chances of this happening in the first place. Partially processed messages are part of the session so after reconnecting with cleanSession=false they will be resent.